# Exclude Enum on Serialization

Tags: android, gson

I'm using Gson to convert a class to Json. I don't want to map the enum class in the Java object I'm converting. Which is the annotation to exclude it?

Have tried `@Exclude` on the class and on individual members.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2), check the `@Expose` annotation. You can use this annotation to keep the field you want to serialize.

For example, a person entity, I don't want to serialize id to json.

```
public class Person {

    private long id;

    @Expose
    private String name;

    @Expose
    private String intro;

    public Person(long id, String name, String intro) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.intro = intro;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIntro() {
        return intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(String intro) {
        this.intro = intro;
    }
}
```

then I can create `gson` with this code

```
public void serializeWithExpose() {
    Gson g = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    Person person = new Person(1L, "Name", "into");
    String s = g.toJson(person);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```